# Python - efficient way to find first occurences of multiple values

Tags: python, algorithm, numpy

I have a following problem: I need to find first occurences in an array for values greater than or equal than multiple other values.

Example:

```
array_1 = [-3,2,8,-1,0,5]
array_2 = [5,1]
```

Script has to find where in `array_1` is the first value greater than or equal to each value from `array_2` so the expected result in that case would be `[3,2]` for 1-based indices

A simple loop won't be any good for my case as both array have close to million values and it has to execute quickly preferably under a minute.

Simple loop solution that has a run time of about half an hour:

```
 for j in range(0, len(array_2)):
        for i in range(0, len(array_1)):
            if array_1[i] >= array_2[j]:
                solution[j] = i
                break
```

Edit: indices clarification as @Sergio Tulentsev correctly pointed out

Comment: Have you even *tried* any code to see how long it takes?

Comment: Here's an idea off the top of my head: convert the first array into an array of tuples `(value, idx of the value)` and sort it by value. Now, for each element from array_2, you should be able to find the desired element on O(logN) (hint: binary search)

Comment: @ThierryLathuille: indices, not values

Comment: You should clarify that in the question - especially if you want to count indices from 1, as seems to be the case.

Comment: @ThierryLathuille: I'm not the OP :) but yes, those 1-based indices seem suspicious

Comment: Right :) OP should !

Comment: still I do not see [2,3]

Comment: @mikuszefski because it's [3, 2] (or [2, 1] for 0-based indices)

Comment: Is there any limitation of the values? (maybe a quite small set of possible values?)

Comment: anyhow np.argwhere ( array1 >= max(array2) ), should do, right?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev hmm but array_1[1] = 2, which is not greater than 5

Comment: @MrsSmith42 Values can be anywhere from 0 to 10^8

Comment: @mikuszefski you misunderstood the problem. There's no `max(array_2)` here. array_1[1] is greater than 1.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev so it seems. There is something I do not get here. Can someone rephrase the problem?.....ok....got it

Comment: @mikuszefski :shrug: seems pretty clear to me. "for each element in array_2, where in array_1 is the first element that is equal or larger?"

Comment: @SergioTulentsev yep, I already had it, sorry for the confusion

Comment: ...so the simple numpy implementation would be `np.fromiter( ( np.argwhere(a1>=x)[0,0] for x in a2), int)` but in a loop one could save time by looking for the smallest value first, maybe by using `numpy.argsort`

Comment: @A67John: if that hour of runtime is for when two array are having millions elements each, then my O(MlogN) approach outlined above should take only a second or two (at the cost of O(N) memory)

Comment: Can you mention what is the possible range of array elements? I mean how big can they be? If the array size is `n`, then all `A[i]` will be less than `n`? Is this condition satisfied?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First perform some preprocessing on the data: create a new list that only has the values that are greater than all predecessors in the original data, and combine them in a tuple with the 1-based position where they were found.

So for instance, for the example data [-3,2,8,-1,0,5], this would be:

```
[(-3, 1), (2, 2), (8, 3)]
```

Note how the answer to any query can only be 1, 2 or 3, as the values at the other positions are all smaller than 8.

Then for each query use a binary search to find the tuple whose left value is at least the queried value, and return the right value of the found tuple (the position). For the binary search you can rely on the `bisect` library:

```
import bisect 

def solve(data, queries):
    # preprocessing
    maxima = []
    greatest = float("-inf")
    for i, val in enumerate(data):
        if val > greatest:
            greatest = val
            maxima.append((val, i+1))
    # main
    return [maxima[bisect.bisect_left(maxima, (query,))][1]
            for query in queries]
```

Example use:

```
data = [-3,2,8,-1,0,5]
queries = [5,1]
print(solve(data, queries))  # [3, 2]
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using a loop over the first array and using `max(array_2)` for the second one.